# Spring boot swagger ui make automatically updated fields invisible

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a Spring Boot application with the following entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "jokes")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Joke extends BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "content")
  private String content;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  @Column(updatable = false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

My Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/jokes")
  public Joke createJoke(@Valid @RequestBody Joke joke) {
    return jokeRepository.save(joke);
  }
```

The fields `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are automatically updated. I am using `swagger` and when I go on an end point  which allows me to create a new resource, then swagger gives me the option of updating the fields `createdAt` and `updatedAt` at as well as shown below. The are not actually being updated, but I would like to not see them there. Anyone knows how I could do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fileds to be hidden only at the Swagger level, you can do it with the `@Schema` annotation of Swagger

```java
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  @Column(updatable = false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  @Schema(hidden = true)            // One way to do it
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @UpdateTimestamp
  @Schema(accessMode = READ_ONLY)  // Other way to do it
  private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

The difference between the two of them is, `hidden` will remove the property from Schema component which will make it unavailable for both request and response payloads while `accessMode` will hide it only for request payloads and not show the access mode in the Schema component as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.7/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html).

> ### accessMode:
>
> Allows to specify the access mode (AccessMode.READ_ONLY, READ_WRITE) AccessMode.READ_ONLY: value will not be written to during a request but may be returned during a response. AccessMode.WRITE_ONLY: value will only be written to during a request but not returned during a response. AccessMode.READ_WRITE: value will be written to during a request and returned during a response.

> ### hidden:
>
> Allows schema to be marked as hidden.

And if you want it to be ignored by the JSON parser that you're using, you'll need something like `JsonIgnore` if you're using Jackson as the parser.

```java
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  @Column(updatable = false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  @JsonIgnore                       // Jackson will ignore this field
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @UpdateTimestamp
  @JsonIgnore                      // this will also be ignored
  private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```